# How do you write the name of a cube?

Tags: geometry, definition, 3d, convention

This is kind of a silly question but here goes.

Is there any accepted convention for the order in which you list the vertices when you write the name of, say a cube? (This could also be extended to a couple of other 3D objects, I guess.)

For example, there's this question talking about a cube $ABCDA_1B_1C_1D_1$. I thought of it with the vertices A, B, C, and D on the bottom, and the ones named similarly to them right above, and it happened to be the cube the question was talking about. I could stop with that, but that isn't the only way to do this.

If you draw a cube and then label the vertices one by one, going in a straight line around the edges, there are two ways you could label the vertices after reaching D, too.

I ask because without some convention, this could lead to some ambiguity.

Comment: In general labeling things is an arbitrary choice so unless you have some specific application in mind such as with a winged edge data structure there wouldn't be any reason to prefer one over the other.

Comment: The cube has 48 symmetries (half of which are realized by rotations, and the other half require some reflection also).  So it's not as simple to describe a conventional way to label the vertices of a cube as it is for a square.  Typically it will be necessary for an author to explain such a labeling, for example by referring to the coordinates of the vertices.  Note that the edges of a cube admit a closed tour of the vertices, but ordering the vertices in this fashion might not be the most helpful way.